# How to fix variable does not exist in current context in SharePoint WebPart code behind?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am a complete noob when it comes to developing webparts for SharePoint 2010. I have created a webpart that has button on it. When that button is clicked, I would like it to redirect the user to another page. That would seem like an easy operation to do but I have run into roadblocks.

In my MyWebPart.ascx.cs file, I have the following bit of code:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the values the user inputted
        try
        {
            String category = SearchBySelector.SelectedValue;
            String keyword = SearchField.Text;
            SPWeb root = SPContext.Current.RootWeb.Url;
            String url = root + "/path/to/site.aspx?category=" + category + "&keyword=" + keyword;
            SPUtility.Redirect(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = "#FF0000";
            StatusLabel.Text = "Exception encountered." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that SPContext (and SPUtility) is not being recognized in this context. How do I fix this? I assume I need some sort of include somewhere? I am not a C# expert either which is probably evident by my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the fully qualified namespaces for both SPContext and SPUtility, which are `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility` respectively.

You can either use those fully qualified class names in your code, or tack two `using` statements onto the top of your code file:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
```

If Visual Studio still barks at you about not recognizing these types or namespaces, you'll want to be sure the `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly is added to the references in your project. You can add references from the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank-you very much for the great answer.